# Sails.js (Node.js) server architecture, scaling and performance

Tags: node.js, server, architecture, sails.js, scaling

I want to create Sails.js (Node.js) server app, which will provide API for single-page-app. This server will consist of multiple modules:

- user management
- forum
- chat
- admin GUI
- content management
- payment gateway
- ...

All these modules will share one database. The server must be able to handle as many requests and web sockets as possible. Clean architecture and performance are my primary goals.

My questions:

1. Should I create multiple servers running on multiple ports? I mean, one server for content management module. Another server for forum management module.
2. Or is it better to create only one big universal server, which will consists of multiple separate modules (hooks in Sails.js) and runs on one port? Will performance of the server decrease in this case ?

I was thinking about vertical scaling one big universal server, running on single port with [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). Or is it better to scale Node.js horizontaly and split server to multiple smaller servers ?

Im new to Node.js so I appreciate any advice.

Comment: I think that in general this is not a concern regarding node.js itself. This is a common scaling problem regarding any backend technology. Actually I would be glad to read an answer about how this is done properly. I have some ideas, but I am not sure if they are good enough. Maybe you should read more about load balacers.

Comment: Define "payment gateway". Do you intend on processing card payments via your website/application or via an external payment gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I think it really boils down to the scale of the project.

For very simple things there's no real reason to scale past a single but reliable server is there?

However for broader projects that have a back-end that is resource intensive and a lot of users and traffic, you may a want to split the back / front end aspects depending on the requirements.

In which case you might have a single server (or more) dealing with the specific administrative requests or routines then have the client / user API running through a load balancer and spread across multiple servers in multiple regions or break it down further into an auto scaling group so as to accommodate for fluctuations in traffic.

It would be worthwhile to note too that this is really suited for higher volumes of traffic or resource usage as you're dedicating the server infrastructure for this purpose, for smaller applications where there is infrequent usage then breaking things down into micro services from the start and getting billed for the runtime rather than dedicated infrastructure utilization might make more sense to me. You could take a look at AWS API Gateway and Lambda services for some more information on that (I am not affiliated to AWS in any way, I just appreciate what they have managed to put together there).